# Custom FavIcon Angular

Tags: angular, frontend

I have a project that is used in many places with the same angular code, but different docker files.

I need to change the favicon just to one place, without changing it to the others. How can I do it?

I've tried to use copy in docker file but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to copy the file into the created dist folder.

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
# ... Build Angular and so on
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY dist/angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html
# Here copy the new logo in the project
COPY favicon_app1.ico /usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico
```